# Link dylib library

Tags: xcode, macos, makefile, clang, dylib

I'm trying to link a dylib to my makefile on Mac, but Clang gives this message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_zbesj_wrap", referenced from:
  sp_bessel::besselJ(double, std::__1::complex<double>) in besselJ.o
"_zbesy_wrap", referenced from:
  sp_bessel::besselJ(double, std::__1::complex<double>) in besselJ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I installed the library in /usr/lib, where I can see libcomplex_bessel.0.6.0.dylib and libcomplex_bessel.dylib. 
This is my makefile:

```
OBJS = main.o besselJ.o
CC = c++
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
LIBS = -L/usr/lib -lcomplex_bessel
PROGRAM_NAME = test

all: $(PROGRAM_NAME)
$(PROGRAM_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 
besselJ.o: besselJ.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(LIBS)
```

After reading other questions, I tried different combinations for -L and -l but nothing worked. Sorry but it's my first time with external libraries...

---

I changed my makefile to this:

```
OBJS = main.o besselJ.o
CC = c++
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
LIBS = -L/usr/lib -lcomplex_bessel
PROGRAM_NAME = test

all: $(PROGRAM_NAME)
$(PROGRAM_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LIBS)
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 
besselJ.o: besselJ.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

but I still have problems, I get this message:

```
c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ main.o besselJ.o -o test -L/usr/lib -lcomplex_bessel
ld: library not found for -lcomplex_bessel
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

---

Ok, I think I solved it using `xcode-select --install`: other users had the same problem with libraries after updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass libs to linker, not to the compiler:

```
OBJS = main.o besselJ.o
CC = c++
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
LIBS = -L/usr/lib -lcomplex_bessel
PROGRAM_NAME = test

all: $(PROGRAM_NAME)
$(PROGRAM_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LIBS)
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 
besselJ.o: besselJ.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I did it but I get this message: 
ld: library not found for -lcomplex_bessel
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)